# Unable to get correct link in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a bit of HTML and I'd like to extract the link that matches a particular pattern. I'm using the `find` method with a regular expression but it doesn't get me the correct link. Here's my snippet. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """
<div class="entry">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/diary_of_a_wimpy_kid/">RT</a>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.imdb.com/video/imdb/vi2496267289/">Trailer</a> &ndash; 
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1196141/">IMDB</a> &ndash; 
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.find('a', href = re.compile(r".*title/tt.*"))['href']
```

I should be getting the second link but BS always returns the first link. The `href` of the first link doesn't even match my regex so why does it return it?

Thanks.

Comment: I've corrected from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup. It shouldn't work if not. Then it returns the 3rd links. I think it works ok.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for some reason. It always gives the first link - `http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/diary_of_a_wimpy_kid/`

Comment: it also works for me (BS v3.1.0.1)., I get the third link. What's your version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` only returns the first `<a>` tag. You want [`findAll`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs%29).

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer your question, but anyway your (originally) posted code has an import typo. Change

```
import BeautifulSoup
```

to

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

Then, your output (using beautifulsoup version 3.1.0.1) will be:

```
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1196141/
```

Comment: My bad. When testing it out on my computer i had BS in a different location and when I copy-pasted the coded here, I modified the `import` hurriedly and therefore the typo. I'll make the edit. The problem still persists though. It doesn't give me the correct link.