# How to get link start end position in html

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following text in HTML format.

```
b'<p><b>Anna Katharina Schaffelhuber</b> (* <a href="/wiki/26._Januar" title="26. Januar">26. Januar</a> <a href="/wiki/1993" title="1993">1993</a> in <a href="/wiki/Regensburg" title="Regensburg">Regensburg</a>) ist eine deutsche <a href="/wiki/Monoskibob" title="Monoskibob">Monoskibobfahrerin</a>. Sie gehört seit April 2017 dem <a href="/wiki/Bundeszollverwaltung#Spitzensportf%C3%B6rderung" title="Bundeszollverwaltung">Zoll-Ski-Team</a> an.<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-1"><a href="#cite_note-1">[3]</a></sup>\n</p>\n'
```

using

`text = format(BeautifulSoup(p,'html.parser').get_text())`

returns

`'Anna Katharina Schaffelhuber (* 26. Januar 1993 in Regensburg) ist eine deutsche Monoskibobfahrerin. Sie gehört seit April 2017 dem Zoll-Ski-Team an.'`

where `format()`is a function I built that will delete undesired parts (indices, line breaks, etc). This works in 99,9% of the cases. So far so good. My next step is extracting the links.

My desired output is something like this:

```
hyperlinks : [{    "id : 0,
                "name" : "26. Januar",
                "link" : "/wiki/26._Januar",
               "start" : 32,
               "end"   : 42 },
               { ... for all the links ... }]
```

I have thought of parsing the raw HTML and deleting all `<b>`s, `<\b>`s, `</a>`s etc. This seems very annoying and I'm not sure if I can catch all cases with this method.

I can't wrap my head around a smooth approach. How can I extract `start`, `end` and `link` for every hyperlink with the information above?

> Possible duplicate of Unable to get correct link in BeautifulSoup

`find()` and `find_all()` methods don't solve the problem for me. Yes, `find_all()` will return a list of all hrefs, but I need the exact position for this one href. I can't just use an element in the list, match it against the text and find out the position that way. It could be anything simple like "Apple" which could be in the text multiple times. But I want the single correct position. I need the position because I want to structure all of wikipedia's content into a large database. Those hyperlinks are information I will use at a later point. They will help me build a huge graph or net of the wikipedia.

Just in case someone is referencing to the wiki dumps: they do not contain link and category information. Besides that the handling of those dumps seems very uncomfortable and unstable to me as maintenance has been stopped in the mid-2000s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to get correct link in BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316415/unable-to-get-correct-link-in-beautifulsoup)

Comment: Don't think `find_all()` method will help much, I need the exact position and `find_all()` just returns a list of all hrefs. They could be anywhere though.

Comment: ***"hyperlinks are information"**: So you need the **hyperlink value**, not the index of the position inside a `html` page.

Comment: Look at my JSON example. I need the information (which I called `link` in my JSON) but most importantly I need `start` and `end` of it. Is my question that ambiguous?? I'm so confused.

Comment: ***"Is my question that ambiguous??"***: Yes, but to satisfy you, read [finding-all-adverbs-and-their-positions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs-and-their-positions)

Comment: what is the `start` and `end` exactly is it the position of the `<a` in the text?

Comment: It's the `start` and `end` position of the hyperlinked word(s) in the actual, cleaned text. I edited it. It's the position of `"name"` (see JSON) in the cleaned text.

Comment: Can you use lxml instead of beutifulsoup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you want. I assume id is just a unique value that increases by 1, since you didn't specify what any of your keys meant.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<p><b>Anna Katharina Schaffelhuber</b> (* <a href="/wiki/26._Januar" title="26. Januar">26. Januar</a> <a href="/wiki/1993" title="1993">1993</a> in <a href="/wiki/Regensburg" title="Regensburg">Regensburg</a>) ist eine deutsche <a href="/wiki/Monoskibob" title="Monoskibob">Monoskibobfahrerin</a>. Sie gehört seit April 2017 dem <a href="/wiki/Bundeszollverwaltung#Spitzensportf%C3%B6rderung" title="Bundeszollverwaltung">Zoll-Ski-Team</a> an.<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-1"><a href="#cite_note-1">[3]</a></sup>\n</p>\n'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
clean_text = 'Anna Katharina Schaffelhuber (* 26. Januar 1993 in Regensburg) ist eine deutsche Monoskibobfahrerin. Sie gehört seit April 2017 dem Zoll-Ski-Team an.'

hrefs = {href.text: href['href'] for href in soup.find_all('a')  if href.get('title')}

hyperlinks = []
for i, (href_text, href) in enumerate(hrefs.items()):
    start = clean_text.index(href_text)
    end = start + len(href_text) - 1
    hyperlinks.append({'id': i,
                       'name': href_text,
                       'link': href,
                       'start': start,
                       'end': end})

print(hyperlinks)
```

Comment: If I looked into this 2 days earlier you would have saved me a lot of time .. I replaced my complicated solution with your simple one. Thank you @LuckyZackary.